# How to set _id to a field from property in mapping in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to define a mapping in elasticsearch wherein _id will be set to one of the field of property in the mapping.
So every time i post data it should automatically extract this field and set it to _id.
But on saving data every time a new random _id is generated. Is this the correct way to set _id when setting mappings in elasticsearch.

```
PUT /index00001
{
"mappings": {
        "_meta":{
            "_id" : "userid"
            },
            "properties": {
                "userid": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "nickname": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
    },
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1,
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    }
}

POST /index00001/_doc
{
    "userid": "6009001",
    "nickname": "nick"
}

{
  "took" : 438,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index00001",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "IeKqnn0BuUqEU88H_tlq",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "userid" : "6009001",
          "nickname" : "nick"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index00001",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "JeKrnn0BuUqEU88HNtnu",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "userid" : "6009001",
          "nickname" : "amit"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Why is my _id not set to userid field from property
This is elasticsearch version - 7.8.0 lucene_version -8.5.1

Comment: Have you lookde at this thread. https://discuss.elastic.co/t/creating-a-custom-id-in-a-mapping/65460

it may help.

Answer (score 1):

It used to be possible to have ES automatically use a field value as the ID of the document [in ES 1.X](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/mapping-id-field.html), but it is [not possible anymore since ES 2.0](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/6730).

Now you need to explicitly pass the ID of your documents when indexing them, otherwise one will be generated for you.

Comment: How does this work when an index is created against a mapping json document.